# Add dynamically multiple columns to data table

Tags: r, data.table

Given a data table with 3 columns (the first two form the key), I'm trying to add a bunch of columns `x_k` with k running from 1 to N

```r
df
>    a    b    c 
1:   1    1    1
2:   1    2    1
3:   1    3    2
```

For each new column `x_k`, its value is calculated by the equation `cos(2 * pi * c / k)` grouped by `a` and `b`.

My approach doesn't seem to work: generating a list of column names then parsing it

```r
df[, eval(parse(text = paste0(paste0("x_", 1:N), " := cos(2 * pi * c / ", 1:N, ")"))), by = .(a,b)]
```

R said `c` not found. How should i correct my approach other than looping through list of column names ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
df[, paste0("x_", 1L:N) := lapply(1L:N, function(k) cos(2 * pi * c / k)), .(a, b)]
```

Comment: That's exactly what i came to after posting the question :D

Comment: Pls feel free to answer your own question or delete.

Comment: I think i'll leave it here for later reference.

Comment: I would use `seq_len(N)`